# How to write IF functions in Python when the condition requires the input to be a special character?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to build a sample calculator in Python. It's expected output for `calculate(2, 3, -)` should be -1.

However, I have a hard time defining the operator.

`if operator == +:` will return a syntax error, but when I do 
`if operator == '+':` I need to write something like `calcuate(3, 4, '+')` to work.

Here are

```
def calculate(x, y, operator):
    if operator == '+':
        print (x + y)
    elif operator == '-':
        print (x - y)
    elif operator == '*':
        print (x * y)
    elif operator == '/':
        print (x / y)
```

Is it possible for me to get rid of the required apostrophes?

Comment: No. … To fill up the required space: no, it's not possible to write just `+` by itself.

Comment: `calculate(2, 3, -)` is simply a syntax error.  Nothing you can possibly do in the definition of `calculate()` can possibly make that a valid way to call it.

Answer (score 2):

```
As the comments indicate you can not simply pass +, -, div.
```

Another option that would simplify your code is to use the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

**Code refactoring using operator module**

```
# We obtain operators we will use from operator module
from operator import add, sub, mul, pow
from operator import truediv as div

def calculator(x, y, op):
  " Calculator applies the passed-in operator to arguments "
  return op(x, y)

# Tests
print(calculator(5, 3, add))
print(calculator(5, 3, sub))
print(calculator(5, 3, mul))
print(calculator(5, 3, div))
print(calculator(5, 3, pow))
```

**Using Your Original String Input**

As @JLPeyret suggests, operators make it easier to use a dictionary for the logic for which operation to choose.

```
def calculator(x, y, op):
      " Calculator applies the passed-in operator to arguments "
    d = {'+', add,
         '-', sub,
         '*', mul,
         '/', div,
         '**', pow}
      return d[op](x, y)

# Tests
print(calculator(5, 3, '+'))
print(calculator(5, 3, '-'))
print(calculator(5, 3, '*'))
print(calculator(5, 3, '/'))
print(calculator(5, 3, '**'))
```

**Outputs in both cases**

```
8
2
15
1.6666666666666667
125
```

Comment: This.  And you can a dict to look up the mapping from your chars to operator’s functions.  But you’ll still need those quotes :-(

Comment: @JLPeyret--can you clarify what you meant by "you'll still need those quotes"?  This version using the operators does not use quotes as the code shows.  Is that just referring to the case of using a dict?

Comment: Oh, I assume he’s going to get ‘-‘ from somewhere and will need to associate it with operator.sub. So, maybe I mis-explained - a dict or other stuff will allow lookup of `sub` and your code indeed doesnt need it, as you point out.  But, at the dict level it’ll be something like `opmap = {‘-‘ : operator.sub, ‘+’: ...}`.  `-` by itself is not a variable or literal, he’ll need to use `’-’`. .

Comment: @JLPeyret--thanks for the explanation and your comments make sense.

Comment: @JLPeyret--added your comment to my answer.